# How to test Singleton class that has a static dependency

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, c#-4.0, singleton

I have a Singleton class that uses the thread-safe Singleton pattern from Jon Skeet as seen in the TekPub video. The class represents a cached list of reference data for dropdowns in an MVC 3 UI.

To get the list data the class calls a static method on a static class in my DAL.

Now I'm moving into testing an I want to implement an interface on my DAL class but obviously cannot because it is static and has only one static method so there's no interface to create. So I want to remove the static implementation so I can do the interface.

By doing so I can't call the method statically from the reference class and because the reference class is a singleton with a private ctor I can't inject the interface. How do I get around this? How do I get my interface into the reference class so that I can have DI and I can successfully test it with a mock?

Here is my DAL class in current form

```
public static class ListItemRepository {

    public static List<ReferenceDTO> All() {
        List<ReferenceDTO> fullList;
        ... /// populate list
        return fullList;
    }
}
```

This is what I want it to look like

```
public interface IListItemRepository {
    List<ReferenceDTO> All();
}

public class ListItemRepository : IListItemRepository {

    public List<ReferenceDTO> All() {
        List<ReferenceDTO> fullList;
        ... /// populate list
        return fullList;
    }
}
```

And here is my singleton reference class, the call to the static method is in the `CheckRefresh` call

```
public sealed class ListItemReference {

    private static readonly Lazy<ListItemReference> instance = 
        new Lazy<ListItemReference>(() => new ListItemReference(), true);

    private const int RefreshInterval = 60;
    private List<ReferenceDTO> cache;
    private DateTime nextRefreshDate = DateTime.MinValue;

    public static ListItemReference Instance {
        get { return instance.Value; }
    }

    public List<SelectListDTO> SelectList {
        get {
            var lst = GetSelectList();
            lst = ReferenceHelper.AddDefaultItemToList(lst);
            return lst;
        }
    }

    private ListItemReference() { }

    public ReferenceDTO GetByID(int id) {
        CheckRefresh();
        return cache.Find(item => item.ID == id);
    }

    public void InvalidateCache() {
        nextRefreshDate = DateTime.MinValue;
    }

    private List<SelectListDTO> GetSelectList() {
        CheckRefresh();
        var lst = new List<SelectListDTO>(cache.Count + 1);
        cache.ForEach(item => lst.Add(new SelectListDTO { ID = item.ID, Name = item.Name }));
        return lst;
    }

    private void CheckRefresh() {
        if (DateTime.Now <= nextRefreshDate) return;
        cache = ListItemRepository.All(); // Here is the call to the static class method
        nextRefreshDate = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(RefreshInterval);
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the singleton based on instance(not based on static), for which you can declare interface like this.

```cs
public interface IListItemRepository
{
    List<ReferenceDTO> All();
}


public class ListItemRepository : IListItemRepository
{
    static IListItemRepository _current = new ListItemRepository();

    public static IListItemRepository Current
    {
        get { return _current; }
    }

    public static void SetCurrent(IListItemRepository listItemRepository)
    {
        _current = listItemRepository;
    }

    public List<ReferenceDTO> All()
    {
        .....
    }
}
```

Now, you can mock IListItemRepository to test.

```cs
    public void Test()
    {
        //arrange
        //If Moq framework is used,
        var expected = new List<ReferneceDTO>{new ReferneceDTO()};

        var mock = new Mock<IListItemRepository>();           
        mock.Setup(x=>x.All()).Returns(expected);

        ListItemRepository.SetCurrent(mock.Object);

        //act
        var result = ListItemRepository.Current.All();

        //Assert
        Assert.IsSame(expected, result);
    }
```

Comment: Where is `Mock`coming from? I assume a framework but I mean which one?

Comment: Oh. It means any mock object. You can use any mocking framework(Moq/RhinoMock...) or hand coded mock class.

Comment: This has actually worked. I don't know why I didn't think of it before but I was using a static repository and it wasn't thread safe. By using your example and my thread safe code I got it. I still can't inject `IListItemRepository` into the caching reference class but it lets me use the interface with the repository and then I took the same approach with the reference class :-) awesome thanks!!

Comment: Could you give me more information about why you cannot inject the interface into the caching?

Comment: Private ctor on a thread safe class basically. In this series of videos http://tekpub.com/productions/cspatterns Jon Skeet shows how using what we think are singleton classes aren't true singletons. He compares several methods and show how each one fail. Then he shows the pattern I have in my question using the `Lazy<T>` and a private constructor and it provides a true singleton class. I've already looked into some of the DI frameworks and their methods that are supposed to provide a singleton are using the failed strategies that Jon demonstrated.

Comment: @AlfalfaStrange: There is something that I do not know about singlenton pattern. It sounds like that the singleton we understand may not be true on some extreme case. I hope you can resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Which DI framework are you using?  Depending on your answer, IOC container should be able to handle single-instancing so that you don't have to implement your own singleton pattern in the caching class.  In your code you would treat everything as instanced classes, but in your DI framework mappings you would be able to specify that only one instance of the cache class should ever be created.

Comment: I haven't implemented an IoC framework yet, I was considering Ninject but the documentation and lack of up to date tutorials is horrible. Castle Windsor has a great tutorial so I was considering that one because it shows me how to fix the controllers. I'm still struggling over how to build the DI into the solution (where to put the root, how to reference, etc). Would love to see a good sample of DI in an NTier app

Comment: I'm not an expert on DI myself, but I believe that every major DI framework will support singleton instancing.

Autofac:  http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/InstanceScope
Unity:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660864%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx
Ninject:  http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/03/ninject-life-cycle-management-or-scoping/
StructureMap:  http://abstractcode.com/abstractblog/archive/2010/06/13/structuremap-part-2-ndash-instance-lifecycles.aspx

Comment: That makes sense, but since I can't see *how* it's handling it, I feel *safer* with my thread-safe class with the Lazy<T> instancing :-)

Comment: How = by being the central point where instances of the object are created.  It could either create a new instance each time or use some sort of registry or similar pattern to ensure single instancing.  Some DI frameworks will let you specify an existing instance as the singleton instance of choice.  Still, if you want to embrace DI and be able to supply testable mocks, you will probably want to avoid creating your own static singleton instances and "have faith" in the DI framework.

Comment: I would if I hadn't watched Jon Skeet's video on TekPub where he proves that all the locking/volitile/sync patterns that most people use to try to create a *real* singleton all fail at that. And then he showed how to do it and it never fails. So I'm sure you can see where I struggle with that :-) I've read the docs on Ninject and see that it doesn't implement true singleton, I'm looking into the rest :-)

Answer (score 0):

One way to test it would be if you refactor your ListItemReference by adding extra property:

```
public sealed class ListItemReference {
    ...
    public Func<List<ReferenceDTO>> References = () => ListItemRepository.All();
    ...
    private void CheckRefresh() {
        if (DateTime.Now <= nextRefreshDate) return;
        cache = References();
        nextRefreshDate = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(RefreshInterval);
    }
}
```

And then in your test you could do:

```
ListItemReference listReferences = new ListItemReference();
listReferences.References = () => new List<ReferenceDTO>(); //here you can return any mock data
```

Of course it's just temporary solution and I would recommend getting rid of statics by using IoC/DI.