# Verifying a virtual method (MOQ)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

So I am new to TDD and here is my problem:

I have a class with several methods. Something like this:

```
public class CompanyService : ICompanyService
{
    public ICompanyRepository companyRepository;
    public CompanyService() : this(new CompanyRepository())
    {                
    }

    public CompanyService(ICompanyRepository repository)
    {
        companyRepository = repository;
    }


    public virtual bool InsertCompany(Company company)
    {   
        return companyRepository.InsertCompany(company);
    }

    public bool InsertCompany(Company company, int total)
    {
        if (AddTotals(total))
        {
            return this.InsertCompany(company);
        }

        return false;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Wrapper for the static method at static service
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="total"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public virtual bool AddTotals(int total)
    {
        return StaticService.AddTotals(total);
    }
}
```

Most of my tests run fine for this class. So here is my unit test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Unit_AddTotals()
    {
         var service = new CompanyService();
         Assert.IsFalse(service.AddTotals(1));
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Unit_InsertCompany_IsExecuted()
    {
        Guid id = GenerateCustomerID();
        var company = new Company { CustomerID = id, CompanyName = "CFN-" + id };
        var mock = new Mock<CompanyService>();
        mock.Setup(t => t.AddTotals(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(true);
        mock.Object.InsertCompany(company, 1);
        mock.Verify(t => t.InsertCompany(It.IsAny<Company>()),Times.Once);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Unit_InsertCompany_IsSuccess()
    {
        Guid id = GenerateCustomerID();
        var company = new Company { CustomerID = id, CompanyName = "CFN-" + id };
        var mock = new Mock<CompanyService>();
        mock.Setup(t => t.AddTotals(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(true);
        mock.Setup(t => t.InsertCompany(It.IsAny<Company>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(true);
        Assert.IsTrue(mock.Object.InsertCompany(company, 1));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Unit_StaticService()
    {
        var rep = new Mock<ICompanyRepository>();
        rep.Setup(t => t.InsertCompany(It.IsAny<Company>())).Returns(true);

        var serviceMock = new Mock<ICompanyService>();
        serviceMock.Setup(t => t.AddTotals(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(true);

        Assert.IsTrue(serviceMock.Object.AddTotals(0));
    }

    private Guid GenerateCustomerID()
    {
        return Guid.NewGuid();
    }
```

So when I make my 2 parameter InsertCompany method virtual my IsExecuted method fails at Verify, if I make it non-virtual, then I can't mock it for IsSuccess method and it fails..

Could you please tell me what I am missing with your TDD expertise?

Comment: You don't usually mock the class you are testing.  You would mock the things it is dependent on, in this case the CompanyRepository.

Answer (score 1):

As has been suggested in the comments, you're almost certainly not testing the right thing.  Look at this test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_Unit_InsertCompany_IsSuccess()
{
    Guid id = GenerateCustomerID();
    var company = new Company { CustomerID = id, CompanyName = "CFN-" + id };
    var mock = new Mock<CompanyService>();
    mock.Setup(t => t.AddTotals(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(true);
    mock.Setup(t => t.InsertCompany(It.IsAny<Company>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(true);
    Assert.IsTrue(mock.Object.InsertCompany(company, 1));
}
```

If your class is marked with the right virtual state for the Setup to execute, then you're not actually testing any of your class at all.  You're setting up the Mock to return true when a method is called, then asserting that when you call the method the mock returns true...  You're just testing that you've set your Mocks up correctly.

When you mark the method as virtual, your mocking used in the `IsExecuted` method is failing, because you're calling virtual methods from within the class under test.  If you don't tell it to, Moq will assume that if you're doing a partial mock, you only want your mocked virtuals to be called, not the existing implementation.  You can override this by telling Moq to call your existing implementation by setting the `CallBase` flag.

Your test would then become this:

```
[Test]
public void Test_Unit_InsertCompany_IsExecuted() {
    Guid id = GenerateCustomerID();
    var company = new Company { CustomerID = id, CompanyName = "CFN-" + id };
    var mock = new Mock<CompanyService>();
    mock.CallBase = true;
    mock.Setup(t => t.AddTotals(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(true);
    mock.Setup(t => t.InsertCompany(It.IsAny<Company>()));
    mock.Object.InsertCompany(company, 1);
    mock.Verify(t => t.InsertCompany(It.IsAny<Company>()), Times.Once);
}
```

Two things to note are

1. In the above test, CallBase=true is used to execute existing code.
2. As a result of 1, it's necessary to perform a Setup for the call you want to verify, otherwise the call will actually execute the underlying code and call out to the repository.

Testing that one method calls another method in the same class isn't really a great idea.  It can get very messy and makes it difficult to know that what you're expecting to happen is actually what's happening as well as tightly coupling your implementation to your test code.

You've already setup your Company class to allow the injection of a repository.  Testing that the appropriate repository interactions take place would result in less coupling to the implementation of your Company class and would probably result in more straightforward mocking.

Using that approach, your IsExecuted test might become:

```
[Test]
public void Test_Unit_InsertCompany_SavesToRepository() {
    Guid id = GenerateCustomerID();
    var repoMock = new Mock<ICompanyRepository>();
    var company = new Company { CustomerID = id, CompanyName = "CFN-" + id };
    var mock = new Mock<CompanyService>(repoMock.Object);
    mock.CallBase = true;
    mock.Setup(t => t.AddTotals(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(true);
    mock.Object.InsertCompany(company, 1);
    repoMock.Verify(t => t.InsertCompany(It.IsAny<Company>()), Times.Once);
}
```

Ideally, you'd be able to Mock the interaction with StaticService.AddTotals, that way you would be able to instantiate an actual CompanyService, rather than a mock object in your tests, however that seems out of scope for your current problem...

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback. As you can see I am a total TDD newbie. I agree I should pass the repository mock to the service as its already injected. What I was trying is to make sure every code of the line is covered for the code coverage in VS, I guess I exagerrated a bit..

How would you mock the interaction with StaticService.AddTotals for the knowledge of others and me in the process? Thanks

Comment: @TDDNewbie Static method calls can't be mocked without using something like TypeMock, so if I wanted to, I would look at modifying the structure.  I'd ask why it's static, consider wrapping it in an interface, possibly as a singleton if necessary, so that it could be injected/overriden when needed, something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10939204/592182 might work.  Depending what the method does, you might decide that it's ok to add that dependency into your test and pass appropriate data to modify it's behaviour.  The best approach really depends on your existing code and approaches..